# Download latest ABP with AdminBSBMaterialDesign UI not adminlte UI

Tags: angular-material, frontend, aspnetboilerplate, adminlte

I've downloaded the latest version of Asp.net boilerplate but I noticed that official UI for ABP became **Adminlte** not **AdminBSBMaterialDesign** I want to download latest ABP with AdminBSBMaterialDesign because **Adminlte** does not work with angular material even If I imported all Modules and when I import materiliza.css the whole design for it will be crashed.

so how could I specify which UI I want to download with ABP before downloading it

**Update:**

Here is a screenshot for UI for the ABP framework() when I download it in 2019:
[image]
Here is a screenshot for UI fo the  ABP framework when I download it in this month :

[image]

what I want is I wanna go back for old UI

Comment: The latest template uses AdminLTE. What does it mean to download the latest template without the latest code?

Comment: @aaron if you try to download the ABP framework today you will find that the UI is totally different

Comment: So you just want the old code?

Comment: Yes, that what I wanted

Comment: to know why I want that you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433895/angular-material-doesnt-work-with-adminlte-ui-that-attached-with-abp-5-6-0)

Comment: You downloaded before but deleted it?

Comment: yes, and I've it with a different project but I don't want to change the name of packages manually because I think it not the best practice

Comment: There is no way to download an older version from the website. You can download from the source repo [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template)'s [v5.4.0](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/releases/tag/v5.4.0) release, but you still have to rename the packages yourself.

Comment: @aaron after of many attempts it looks like change the solution name is not an easy task all my attempts end with failer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from @aaron comment

There is no way to download an older version from the website. You can download from the source repo aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template's v5.4.0 release, but you still have to rename the packages yourself.