# Angular material doesn't work with adminlte UI that attached with ABP 5.6.0

Tags: angular-material, aspnetboilerplate, adminlte

Why angular material does not work with **adminlte** template I've imported all angular material component by app.module.ts but when I use mat-select it didn't work the design totally crashed such as below Screenshot :
[image]

My code is identical to [this](https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts)

**another screen shoot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ASPNETZero use ngx-bootstrap rather than angular material, so ngx-bootstrap is already installed and you can use its components, you can find the components her https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#getting-started

Comment: I know but my problem was I've lots of components that I built them by Angular Material So if I use ngx-bootstrap I'll waste my time on things that already I did it by Angular Material

Comment: So I tried to invoke Angular Material for old components and I was trying to build any new component by ngx-bootstrap but when I invoked angular material to the AdminLTE Template the whole templated design dmaged

Comment: whats is the angular version you are used?
I think from angular 9 and up you can't you import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material';
but you must use it like this 
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';

Comment: I used Angular 8, I tried that but with no luck, I think something related to CSS confliction (if you look at screen shoot that I attached I used normal radio button it knew it's Angular Material radio button but without their style)